# Aggregation queries and MongoRepository

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation, mongorepository

How can I use MongoRepository to execute (sometimes complex) aggregation queries? If it is impossible I have to use MongoTemplate?

Comment: It’s not possible yet. Check here https://jira.spring.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/DATAMONGO-2153

Comment: so I have to use MongoTemplate instead?

Comment: Yes for the time being

Comment: Fine! Thanks a lot